# Do I have to have a nonce for a custom comment field?

Tags: comments, validation

im working on my comment section and I have added a custom field

```
<input type="hidden" name="be_user_star_rating" id="be_user_star_rating" value="" />
```

Its value is beign set by Javascript.

Validating it with something like this:

```
add_action( 'comment_post', 'be_comment_rating_insert_comment', 10, 1 );
function be_comment_rating_insert_comment( $comment_id )
{
    if( isset( $_POST['be_user_star_rating'] ) 
        && $_POST['be_user_star_rating'] > 0
        && $_POST['be_user_star_rating'] <= 5
        && is_numeric($_POST['be_user_star_rating']) ) {

        $val  = (int) $_POST['be_user_star_rating'];
        update_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'be_user_star_rating', esc_attr( $val ) );
    } 
}
```

Since this is hooked into `comment_post`, do I have to worry about checking custom nonces - beyond my validation? Or will Worpdress take care of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [WordPress Nonce](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces), while not a *true* nonce, functions similarly in that it exists to secure a form or page from unauthorized access and abuse.

By default, the WordPress Comment Form only displays a nonce field if the current user has the `unfiltered_html` capability.

So, if the form is implemented with standard procedures, all you have to do is validate your own input, and you don't have to mess with nonces.

From **comment-template.php**:

```
/**
 * Display form token for unfiltered comments.
 *
 * Will only display nonce token if the current user has permissions for
 * unfiltered html. Won't display the token for other users.
 *
 * The function was backported to 2.0.10 and was added to versions 2.1.3 and
 * above. Does not exist in versions prior to 2.0.10 in the 2.0 branch and in
 * the 2.1 branch, prior to 2.1.3. Technically added in 2.2.0.
 *
 * Backported to 2.0.10.
 *
 * @since 2.1.3
 */
```

Comment: I knew about the nonce being shown for admins. But its satisfying to know, that there is no validation required on my side, apart from the regular validation/sanitization. Thats answers my question, cheers.